# How to specify number of digits in a float number in php?

Tags: php, function, double, digits

The number is: `1234.56789` or maybe '-1234.56789'

What is the php function to specify we have 4 digits before `.` and 5 digits after `.` ?

Something like this:

```
intNumber(1234.56789);   //4
floatNumber(1234.56789); //5
```

Edit:
Actually I want to check if this number has 4 digits before (.) and 5 digits after (.). If yes I save it to database, and if not, I don't save it in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) in PHP with an extra parameter called `precision`.

```
<?php
echo round(1234.56789,4); //"prints" 1234.5679
                    //^--- The Precision Param
```

**`EDIT :`**

> Thanks a lot. Actually I want to check if this number has 4 digits
> before (.) and 5 digits after (.). If yes I save it to database, and
> if not, I don't save it in the database.

### This one is a bit hacky though..

```
<?php

function numberCheck($float)
{
    $arr=explode('.',$float);
    if(strlen(trim($arr[0],'-'))==4 && strlen($arr[1])==5)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

if(numberCheck(1234.56789))
{
    echo "You can insert this number !";
}
else
{
    echo "Not in the correct format!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I want to check if this number has 4 digits before (.) and 5 digits after (.). If yes I save it to database, and if not, I don't save it in the database. Is it possible to use round() for this job?

Comment: @ParsaSoroori, You can't make use of `round()` for that though. I have added an alternate solution.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that but what about minus numbers (-1234.56789) and I was looking for a php function do it automatically. Anyway it was the best I think.

Comment: @ParsaSoroori, You could just replace the `if` with this `if(strlen(trim($arr[0],'-'))==4 && strlen($arr[1])==5)`

Comment: OK thanks. Sorry for my poor programming. I'm starter.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can't get what I want from number_format so I did this and it works fine :

```
public function floatNumber($number)
 {
      $number_array = explode('.',$number);
      $left = $number_array[0];
      $right = $number_array[1];
      return number_format($number,strlen($right));
 }
```

**number_format() Example :**

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One another solution using string functions to get the count of digits before and after decimal points

```
$num = 1234.43214;
$aftDecimal = strlen(substr(strrchr($num, "."), 1));
$befDecimal = strlen($num)- ($aftDecimal+1);
```